# How to add two payment prices to contact form 7 in wordpress using PayPal and Stripe Addon

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I've been using the CF7 PayPal and Stripe addon streamlessly. Now I want the user to be able to select prices to pay from a drop down. How do I set their select price for payment.

**Screenshot of my contact form:**
[image: Screenshot of my contact form]

**CF7 code:**

```
<div class="column one-second"><p class="big">Options</p>[select* price-option "20 invitations    $100" "40 invitations   $170"]</div>
<div class="column one-second"><p class="big">Your Contact Email:</p>[email* your-email placeholder "Your e-mail"] </div>
<div class="column one"><p class="big">A description of your targeted membership candidates:
</p>[textarea background-experience x5 placeholder "A description of your targeted membership candidates:"]</div>
<div class="column one-second">Pay $100 or $170 [select* group-recruitment "Pay with PayPal|paypal" "Pay with Credit Card|stripe"]</div>
<div class="column one">[submit class:button_full_width "Submit your Article"]</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need the Pro version of the addon:

> You can link any Contact Form 7 form item such as dropdown menus, checkboxes, radio buttons and input boxes to the price, quantity, description or text fields in PayPal and Stripe.

([Source](https://wpplugin.org/downloads/contact-form-7-paypal-add-on/))